# How can I count all the numbers in a text file?

Tags: c++, c

I have a text file like below read.txt:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2.0 3.0 4.0 6
5.0 7 1.0 5.0
```

calc.cpp:

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("read.txt","r");
    double *read_feature = new double*[3];

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) 
        read_feature[i] = new double[3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%lf",&read_feature[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to count all the numbers in my text file (read.txt). Read text file consist of floating and integer number. Answer for the above file would be 12.

How can I count floating number in a file using c++ dynamically? That means without giving the value of i and j. I need program will automatically calculate total number of i and j.

Comment: I thought it's 12 instead of 9. :)

Comment: How do you get 9 out of those numbers?

Comment: Instead of having a separate loop to allocate `read_feature[i]`, why not do it in the outer loop before reading?

Comment: Also, besides the use of `new` this isn't much C++, more like basic C.

Comment: Is it always a matrix input? or can you have different number of inputs per line?

Comment: yes, always matrix input.

Comment: @user2036891 You can't assume that.  You're reading from outside the program, and who knows what a user might do.  _If_ there is a requirement that it be a matrix, and if there is a requirement that the file not contain any other text than floating point, you can probably just output an error and abort if this is not the case, but you still have to check for it.

Comment: @billz Depending on what he means, it's either 12 or 5.  It's still not clear to me what he's trying to do.  (There are only five floating point numbers in his example, although some of them occur multiple times.)

Comment: Your use of the words `calculate` and `total` is ambiguous. `Calculate` usually means carry out some arithmetic, `total` can mean `all`, or `to add up`. So when you say `calculate total` it sounds like you want to add up the values. However, you really want to count how many values you have. This is why I changed the title of your question. Please don't put the word `total` in again.

Answer (score 7):

Do you need to build the array?

Or just count the number of floats?

```
 int main()
 {
     std::ifstream   file("read.txt");
     std::cout << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<double>(file),
                                std::istream_iterator<double>());
 }
```

Comment: This is clearly the best solution, but it's lacking any error checking.  You probably want to check `file.eof()` _after_ calling `distance`, to ensure that you stopped because of end of file, rather than because of something that couldn't be parsed as a floating point.

Comment: In my file, I have 907 lines and each line has 1000 elements. So the value would be 907000. But your program gave output 907440. It seems wrong.

Comment: I have changed my problem statement. Now, how can i calculate total number in my file? File consists of integer and floating point number.

Comment: @user2036891: If the output was 907440 I would suggest that your file contains that many numbers in sequence. The above code is not complicated enough to contain errors. (if the input file contains errors it may not notice `25.567.567` would be parsed as `25.567` and `0.567` for example unless you turned on some specific local (to make `.` the thousands separator or something).

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in counting the number of elements (floating point numbers in this case) in a file, you can read the file into an `std::ifstream`, then use a `std::istream_iterator` to get iterators to the first and the equivalent of one past the end elements. Using these with `std::distance` steps through the elements and returns the number of steps. This is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
int count_elements (std::istream &is) 
{ 
   std::istream_iterator<T> start(is), end;
   return std::distance(start, end);
}

int main()
{
  std::ifstream is("read.txt");
  std::cout << "Number of numbers " << count_elements<double>(is) << std::endl;
}
```

Note: I have omitted error checking here, I leave it up to the user. Also note that if there is an element that cannot be interpreted as a floating point number, the algorithm stops counting. So you get a non-zero result corresponding to the number of elements until the illegal one.

Comment: In my file, I have 907 lines and each line has 1000 elements. So the value would be 907000. But your program gave output 907440. It seems wrong.

Comment: @user2036891 I would suspect there is something wrong with your file. I will try to reproduce it though.

Comment: I have changed my  problem statement. Now, how can i calculate total number in my file? File consists of integer and floating point number.

Comment: @user2036891 well, you could use `count_elements<std::string>(is)`, although that will accept non-numeric stuff too. If you are sure you only have floating point or integers in the file, then it is OK. But if you have any other stuff in there by error, it will count it too.

Comment: In my file, I have 907 lines and each line has 1000 integer or floating point number. So the total number of value would be 907000. But your program gave output 906132.

Comment: @user2036891 open the file in an editor, go to line 906, and see what happens to element 133.

Comment: I don`t understand "see what happens to element 133.". Would you please explain?

Comment: @user2036891 I mean there must be some weird character in your file, straight after element 132 in line 906.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the file contains only floating numbers, in order to find total numbers of floating number, you can count the dots from your file:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("read.txt","r");
char c;
int nFloat=0;
while(!feof(fp))
{
   fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
   if (c=='.')  //is a dot from a floating number
       nFloat++;
}
```

Comment: @user2036891 note that idiomatic C++ (see Loki and my answer) allow you to do this in 2 lines of code, without need for explicit loops or counters. This is a C solution.

Comment: @user2036891 It's not C++ though.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain It's not correct, either.  Looping with `!feof(fp)` in C is the same as looping with `!f.eof()` in C++.  And it's not idiomatic for C either; you don't use `fscanf` to read a single character, you use `getc`.  And finally, not all dots are necessarily floating point numbers, and not all floating point numbers contain dots.

Comment: In my file, I have 907 lines and each line has 1000 elements. So the value would be 907000. But your program gave output 906537. It seems wrong.

Comment: @user2036891 Than your file doesn't have only floating point number. Look at loki answer.

Comment: I have changed my problem statement. Now, how can i calculate total number in my file? File consists of integer and floating point number.

Comment: @user2036891 Yes, you can count the spaces:D

Answer (score -2):

Working on the answer from banuj. You can count the number of floats in one line and number of lines

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("read.txt","r");
char c;
int nFloatrow=0,nfloatcol=0,count=1;
while(!feof(fp))
{
   fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
   if (c=='.'&&count==1)  //is a dot from a floating number
       nFloatrow++;
   if (c=='\n')  //is a newline
   {
       nFloatcol++;
       count=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Another answer which is simply incorrect (and is C, rather than C++).  I'm curious where people learn this.  I'm used to seeing `while ( !f.eof() )` in C++, because there are a couple of web sites out there that do this, even though it is incorrect.  But until this question, I'd never seen `while ( !feof( fp ) )`;  all of the traditional C tutorial texts do it correctly, and C programmers generally learned the language before the web became widespread.

Comment: I have changed my problem statement. Now, how can i calculate total number in my file? File consists of integer and floating point number.